# Decompose the Laplace transform of autocorrelation function of a stachastic process using Wiener-Kolmogorov whitening procedure

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441255/deriving-stochastic-differential-equations-from-autocorrelation) I read that it is possible to use the Wiener-Kolmogorov whitening procedure to decompose the Laplace transform of autocorrelation function into the product of white noise and a system function:
$$\mathcal{L}_{R}(s) =   W(s) H(-s) H(s)$$
Unfortunately, I cannot understand this passage. Why should the transform of the autocorrelation function give this result? Why does $-s$ appear in the argument of $H$?

To answer this question it would be enough to recommend a good reference to study because I don't know the Wiener-Kolmogorov whitening procedure. I thought it was the Wiener filter, but it seems to be something else. I also found this procedure in an old [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/624345), accessible only for a fee. It says:

[image]